# How to display all input elements inside an input-group with the same height? (Bootstrap + Demo)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

Iam building a time input field (Hours & Minutes) via Bootstrap.

Ive googled a lot and came up with a solution.
But the problem is, that the Hour and Minute fields are not on one line.

How can both inputs have the same height?

Demo:
https://www.bootply.com/BxjISccVMH

Problem:
[image: Problem Picutre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by putting the label in it's own row, and the input group in the next row.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="row ">
          <label>Time</label>
      </div>

      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-xs-12 input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Std.">
          <span class="input-group-addon">:</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Min.">
        </div>
      </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

[Check out my codepen.](https://codepen.io/tlringst/pen/zWYwdr)

Comment: Thank you for taking your time writing a solution! But I needed the label above the input fields (like in the example), to be consistent in design. The solution I came up with:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmvVYq

Comment: Gotcha. I updated my answer to reflect your requirements. Check my codepen now, much cleaner.